# Does apple's CGImageMetadataSetValueWithPath work properly?

Tags: gps, exif

I'm trying to geotag a photo and I'm using this dictionary:

```
var gpsProperties: [(NSString, String)] = [
    ("exif:GPSLongitude", "\(abs(coordinate.longitude))"),
    ("exif:GPSLongitudeRef", coordinate.longitude < 0 ? "W" : "E"),
    ("exif:GPSLatitude", "\(abs(coordinate.latitude))"),
    ("exif:GPSLatitudeRef", coordinate.latitude < 0 ? "S" : "N")]
```

And as far as the exif:GPSLongitude and exif:GPSLatitude saves correctly, the Ref part doesn't. Regardless of what I specify there, the N and E are saved. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug by apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed was a bug in MacOS, with MacOS High Sierra, the bug doesn't exist.